# EF Core: How to access the many side foreign key for multiple many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a simple database with an Instructor table (one side) and a courses table (many sides).

The instructor can be either an author of a course or an editor of a course.

I'm setting up a view to edit the instructors which has a list of courses with check boxes so I can check the courses that the instructor edited and authored.

The way I set up the relationship created 2 foreign keys in the courses table, an `AuthorId` and an `EditorId`.

I'm having trouble accessing those columns in the table since they don't exist in the courses model, they were created by EF with the migration.

In my if statement I need to compare the `Instructor.Id` with the `Courses.AuthorId` to see if this instructor is the author, if so I set the check box as selected. And the same for the `EditorId`.

Here are the model classes:

```
public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Course")]
    public string CourseName { get; set; }

    public Instructor? Author { get; set; }
    public Instructor? Editor { get; set; }
}

public class Instructor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Instructor")]
    public string InstructorName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AuthorId")]
    [DisplayName("Author Of")]
    public ICollection<Course> CoursesAuthored { get; set; } = new List<Course>();

    [ForeignKey("EditorId")]
    [DisplayName("Editor Of")]
    public List<Course> CoursesEdited { get; set; } = new List<Course>();
}
```

Here is the view model:

```
public class EditInstructorCourseViewModel
{
    public string CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public string CourseAuthor { get; set; }
    public string CourseEditor { get; set; }

    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    // I may need a IsEditor and IsAuthor
}
```

Here is the Fluent API to configure this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
                .HasOne(c => c.Editor)
                .WithMany(i => i.CoursesEdited);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
                .HasOne(c => c.Author)
                .WithMany(i => i.CoursesAuthored);
}
```

This ended up creating these columns in the SQL database `Courses` table:

```
Id
CourseName
AuthorId
EditorId
```

And what I have so far in the controller for the `GET` edit method

```
public async Task<IActionResult> EditInstructorCourse(int? id)
{
    var instructor = _context.Instructors
                             .Where(c => c.Id == id).ToList();

    var courses = await _context.Courses
                                .ToListAsync();

    ViewData["InstructorId"] = id;
    ViewData["InstructorName"] = instructor[0].InstructorName;

    var model = new List<EditInstructorCourseViewModel>();

    foreach (var course in courses)
    {
        var editInstructorCourseViewModel = new EditInstructorCourseViewModel
            {
                CourseId = course.Id.ToString(),
                CourseName = course.CourseName
            };

        // if course authorid = instructor id
        // isselected = true, else false
        // same for editorid
        // I may need a IsEditor and IsAuthor in the view model

        if (id == course.) // need to access the AuthorId field
        {
            editInstructorCourseViewModel.IsSelected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            editInstructorCourseViewModel.IsSelected = false;
        }

        model.Add(editInstructorCourseViewModel);
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Using the dot notation the intellisense doesn't show the `AuthorId` in the courses class since there is no property with that name in the model.

Any ideas how I can make this work?

Comment: Your question relates only to EFCore, and has nothing to do with ASP.NET Core. I've edited your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your Course entity and add properties for AuthorId and EditorId:

```
public int Id { get; set; }

[DisplayName("Course")]
public string CourseName { get; set; }

public int AuthorId { get; set; }
public Instructor? Author { get; set; }
public int EditorId { get; set; }
public Instructor? Editor { get; set; }
```

Then you need to configure the property to be used as a foreign key:

```
// the same for AuthorId
modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
            .HasOne(course => course.Editor)
            .WithMany(editor => editor.CoursesEdited)
            .HasForeignKey(course => course.EditorId)
            .DeleteBehavior(DeleteBehavior.NoAction); // or other behavior that suits your use case
```